# Остаток от деления в python. math.remainder vs %

Tags: python, математика

Возьмём для примера C

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("-28%%3 => %d\n", -28%3);
    printf("28%%-3 => %d\n", 28%-3);
    return 0;
}

-28%3 => -1
28%-3 => 1
```

А теперь python

```
from math import remainder
print(-28%3, remainder(-28,3))
print(28%-3, remainder(28,-3))

2 -1.0
-2 1.0
```

Почему так? Почему python при простом остатке от деления возвращает 2?

Comment: Потому что оператор `%` в питоне это modulus. А это не то же самое, что remainder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что в отличии от С, оператор `%` в Python возвращает значение с тем же знаком, что и у делителя. Т.е. добавляется шаг, который вычислит разницу с отрицательным значением.

Вычисление происходит следующим образом

> -28 % 3 = (-9*3 - 1) % 3 = -1 % 3 = -1
>
> 28 % -3 = (9*3 + 1) % -3 = 1 % -3 = 1

В данном случае C останавливается и не выполняет дальнейших действий, но Python приводит значение к тому же знаку, что и делитель.

> -28 % 3 = (-9*3 - 1) % 3 = -1 % 3 = -1 + 3 = 2
>
> 28 % -3 = (9*3 + 1) % -3 = 1 % -3 = 1 - 3 = -2

Подробнее описано [здесь](https://julianpark.me/posts/python-modulo)